# How to upload the raw bytes of image data to facebook

Tags: php, facebook

The program will download the user profile picture and then apply an effect to it via imagemagick. As [facebook example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#images) is only for file base and I dont to want store it as temp file, How can I upload the finalized image in binary format to facebook?

```
<?php 
  //1. prepare frame
  $overlay = new Imagick('1.png');

  //2. prepare base image
  $base = new Imagick();
  $base->readImageFile(fopen('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?type=large', 'rb'));


  //3. finalize the image
  $base->compositeImage($overlay, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);


  //4. prepare form data
  $options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL         => "https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources",
    CURLOPT_POST        => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => Array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => array(
      'file' => 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($base),
      'access_token' => ''
    )
  );

  //5. send to staging_resources 
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  echo curl_exec($ch);

  //6. create og object

?>
```