# Facebook API 100 Error

Tags: php, facebook, actionscript-3

Been receiving this error when trying to post on a feed.  I am using JavaScript to post.
The ByteArray data is coming from a .swf

API Error Code: 100

API Error Description: Invalid parameter

Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted

Here is my AS3:

```
var bdToSave:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s.width,  s.height);
        bdToSave.draw(s, null, null, null, null, true);
        var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
        var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bdToSave);

        if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("publishStream", byteArray);
```

Here is my JS:

```
function publishStream(person)
        {

            FB.ui({ 
                    method : 'feed', 
                    name: 'I just painted my face!',
                    caption: 'From the show Warren, using the True Colors: Face Painting App I painted my face to match my favourite team!',
                    link:  'https://www.facebook.com/fanunitednet',
                    description: '',
                    picture: person
                  });
        }
```

I am sending it a byte array of data.  Is it possible to get it working using that or do I need a URL?  My issue is that I'm taking a picture, sending the bytearray of data to the form and then trying to use that picture.. there is no direct link.

Thoughts?

Comment: Related? http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-25-support/5577-facebook-api-error-100-picture-url-is-not-properly-formatted

Comment: No - I don't want a link for the image, I'm sending in the RAW data.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's possible, or if you need to somehow save/store the file temporarily, link it, and then submit, then delete from server.  Ideas..?

Comment: You might want to track this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968732/how-to-upload-the-raw-bytes-of-image-data-to-facebook

Comment: Without code it is difficult to help you. How are you sending the bytearray, how are you posting?

Comment: @Fygo I've added in my code- hope you can help!  I feel like I may not be sending the data properly either. :S

Comment: @Lagoo87 I am rather positive you cannot pass a bytearray like that from as3 to javascript. You would need to encode it somehow (base64?). What is the need to post it from JS? You can just post it easily from AS3.

Comment: @Fygo I just have the Facebook already set up using JavaScript, so was just reusing and hoping there was a small easy fix- I guess I'll move towards setting it up with AS3.  Any sources you recommend?

Comment: @Lagoo87 This is for mobile mainly but the AS3 api is all you need, the use of it is really simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727572/facebook-abobe-as3-api-for-air-for-mobile

Comment: @Fygo much appreciated. thanks a lot- I'll post answer myself once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the image via the Graph API first, for example like it's described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#publish

This mean via a POST request to `/{user_id}/photos` as *multipart/form-data* mime-type, and the byteArray as source parameter.

Remember that you need the `publish_actions` permission to be able to do this!